# #1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a database in `PHPMyAdmin` and I'm getting the error `#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` after I've already created the table. The code that I have is

```
drop table if exists tbl;

create table tbl(
name varchar(20) primary key,
pword char(30) not null,
mail varchar(50) not null
);
```

And I've tried it in `MySQL Workbench` and that's not giving me any errors at all when it runs

**EDIT**

My other table that references the `tbl` table is

```
create table tbl2(
tbl2_id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20),
primary key (tbl2_id),
foreign key (name) references tbl(name)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that there is a foreign key from another table that refers to a row of your `tbl` table. You can't delete a table if another table has a reference to it, it would mean that one of your table has a foreign key that refers to a table which doesn't exist anymore.

This is what `foreign key constraint fails` mean

Comment: So do you think I should get rid of the foreign key from the other table?

Comment: Yes, first erase every constraint to a table before deleting it. But check if it would be a good idea to do so.. Just update the other table after recreating `tbl` adding the constraint

Comment: I have done that so nothing references to the table and I'm still getting the error

Comment: You have a constraint that is the problem. Can you provide more of your tables so I can see ?

Comment: So, `foreign key (name) references tbl(name)` is the problem as i said. When you are updating the foreign key there is still the error ?

Comment: I've take the `foreign key (name) references tbl(name)` and the `name varchar(20)` out of `tbl2` and I'm still getting the same error and it isn't in any other table. I don't quite understand what you mean when you say about updating the foreign key

Comment: No need to delete `name` field.  First add a name to your constraint then try `alter table tbl2 drop constraint name_constraint`